# issue with alamofire pod on xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift

hello everyone I install `the alamofire` and google places pod to autocomplete the places search
but it gives me the error:

```
The “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) build setting must be set to a 
supported value for targets that use Swift. This setting can be set in the 
build settings editor.
```

my code:

```
    class SetLocationViewController: UIViewController {
    private var placesClient = GMSPlacesClient()
    @IBOutlet weak var setLocationTf: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()
        
        
    }
    
   
    @IBAction func onClickTf(_ sender: Any) {
        setLocationTf.resignFirstResponder()
        let acController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
        acController.delegate = self
        
        let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        filter.type = .establishment
        filter.countries = ["BR"]
        acController.autocompleteFilter = filter
        
        let field: GMSPlaceField = [.name, .placeID]
        acController.placeFields = field
        
        present(acController, animated: true, completion: nil)
       
    }
 

}

    extension SetLocationViewController: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {
        func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
            if let name = place.name {
            setLocationTf.text = name
            }
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error) {
            print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
        }
        func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

The error I got:

[image]

Comment: What is your Alamofire version?

Comment: Use older version

Comment: i use the version -   pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'

Comment: @SPatel please tell me which old version?

Comment: set swift version in Project>Target>BuildSettings>SwiftCompiler-Language> set proper version

Comment: @SPatel when I set the proper version swift 4 or 3 it gives me approximate 70 errors